Ansible Generate random passwords for users
So, I have an ansible role  that is executed via AAP (ansible automation platform)
I need to create a couple of users on different machines, each user, to have an automated generated password
playbook is executed on ansible tower with following extra variables::
action: "present"
group_details:
   - name: 'ssh-user'
     gid:  12500

user_details:
      - name: 'admin-ora'
        comment: 'oracle main user'
        groups: [ 'ssh-user']
        uid: 105 
      - name: 'admin-orainst'
        comment: 'oracle install'
        groups: [ 'ssh-user']
        uid: 106

accounts.yml
---
- set_fact:
    user_details: |
       {{ user_details | map('combine', { "u_pass": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters, digits length=15') }}"}) }}

- name: updated dictionary
  set_fact:
    user_details: "{{ user_details }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{item.u_pass}}"
  loop: "{{user_details}}"

- block:
   - name: Manage groups
     group:
        name: "{{item.name}}"
        gid: "{{item.gid}}"
        state: present
     loop: "{{ group_details }}"
   - name: Manage users [add account]
     user:
       name: "{{ item.name }}"
       comment: "{{item.comment}}"
       uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
       shell: "{{ item.shell|default('/bin/bash')}}"
       groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
       append: yes
       password: "{{item.u_pass}}"
       state: "{{action}}"
     loop: "{{ user_details }}"
     loop_control:
       label: "{{item.name}}"
 

However, during execution I get this error::
ok: [linux-test-server02] => {"ansible_facts": {"user_details": [{"comment": "oracle main user", "groups": ["ssh-user"], "name": "admin-ora", "u_pass": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters, digits length=15') }}"}, {"comment": "oracle install", "groups": ["ssh-user"], "name": "admin-orainst", "u_pass": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters, digits length=15') }}"}]}, "changed": false}

TASK [accounts : updated dictionary] *******************************************
ok: [linux-test-server02] => {"ansible_facts": {"user_details": [{"comment": "oracle main user", "groups": ["ssh-user"], "name": "admin-ora"}, {"comment": "oracle install", "groups": ["ssh-user"], "name": "admin-orainst"}]}, "changed": false}

   
 TASK [accounts : debug] ********************************************************
    fatal: [linux-test-server02]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.\n The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'u_pass'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'u_pass'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/requirements_roles/accounts/tasks/main.yml': line 34, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - debug:\n     ^ here\n"}

I took this as an inspiration: Generate random passwords for users and store them so they can be used later
But... seems like the code still fail to append the password field to dictionary :(

maybe try /dev/random in place of /dev/null

Solved::
- name: Generate random password for each user
  set_fact:
    user_passwords: "{{ user_passwords | default({}) | combine({ item.name: lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits length=15') }) }}"
  loop: "{{ user_details }}

- name: Create users
  user:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
      groups: "{{ item.groups | join(',') }}"
      uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
      password: "{{ user_passwords[item.name] | password_hash('sha512') }}"
        state: "{{ action | default('present') }}"
  loop: "{{ user_details }}"

